# Многократный перенос обсуждения в чат?

Tags: обсуждение, дефект

После переноса обсуждения в чат, предлагается сделать это ещё раз. Зачем?

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: скорее всего проверка на нужность показа этого сообщения никак не зависит от того создавалась ли комната чата или нет, к тому же возможен случай, что при очередном нажатии - будет создана комната для других полльзователей

Comment: и опять же ничего не мешает проигнорировать данное сообщение и продолжить общение не в чате

Comment: Недавно аналогичный баг [словил](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/605658/sizeof-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b#comment826071_606056). Причем, если перейти по ссылке на комментарий, то нет предложения о переносе. А если открыть [ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/606056/176217) и развернуть комментарии, то ссылка есть.